# 2 SSDs, different mount points

Tags: mount, automounting

I have 3 disks:

1. 1TB HDD with 2 partitions. This is where my Ubuntu is installed.
   uuid: 4bed12f2-c8be-4cb8-943b-7a92b810322d
2. 240 GB SSD. uuid: 0f2bd77d-5c9b-412f-be15-a18eabe1a62d
3. 250 GB SSD. uuid: 69ce045f-f1bf-4fa0-9a87-0538255e4f27.

(2) is mounted at `/mnt` and (3) is mounted at `/media`. Why do they have 2 different mount points?

Here is my `/etc/fstab` file contents:

```
UUID=4bed12f2-c8be-4cb8-943b-7a92b810322d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0f2bd77d-5c9b-412f-be15-a18eabe1a62d /mnt/0f2bd77d-5c9b-412f-be15-a18eabe1a62d auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6E64A02252BE633E /mnt/6E64A02252BE633E auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/04d61a9c-897f-42b8-8c7e-b22b89fd3a2e none swap sw 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/69ce045f-f1bf-4fa0-9a87-0538255e4f27 /mnt/69ce045f-f1bf-4fa0-9a87-0538255e4f27 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to tell how can one of your SSDs end up mounted on `/media`. You may find some clue in your logs  - e.g., assuming your version of Ubuntu is systemd-based, `journalctl -b 0 | grep /media`.

Comment: guess 3. is marked/formatted as removeable drive while 2. is marked system drive or contains swap. check gparted and see if there is something different

Comment: Also, the relevant parts of the output of `lsblk -f` may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Linux traditionally has [two mount points](https://learning.lpi.org/en/learning-materials/101-500/102/102.1/102.1_01/):

***/mnt*** was the directory under which all external devices would be mounted and a number of pre-configured anchor points for common devices, like CD-ROM drives (/mnt/cdrom) and floppy disks (/mnt/floppy) existed under it.

This has been superseded by ***/media***, which is now the default mount point for any user-removable media (e.g. external disks, USB flash drives, memory card readers, optical disks, etc.) connected to the system.

[Udev rules](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/beginners-guide-to-udev-in-linux/) are the reason to be mounted in different directories.